# xcassetsからUIImageが読み込めない

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**xcassetsからUIImageが読み込めない問題です。**

以前まで普通に読み込めていた画像が何らかの原因で読み込めず*nil*を返すようになってしまいました。
以下のようなコードです。

```
let img = UIImage(named: "navigation_background")
```

以下のエラーログを吐きます。

```
-[CUIThemeRendition newImageFromCSIDataSlice:ofBitmap: usingColorspace:] Unsupported pixel format in CSI got 4
 Unable to create unsliced image from csi bitmap data.
```

環境は以下の通りです。全てのシミュレータ及び実機で同様に起きます。
Yosemite10.10.5
Xcode6.4

下記のことは全て試しましたが全てダメでした。
・Clean
・DerivedDataのクリア
・アプリ削除&インストール
・Xcode再起動
・シミュレータ(or実機)再起動
・PC再起動
・Xcode削除&再インストール
・別プロジェクト新規作成して画像読みこむだけのアプリで試す
・コマンドラインツールの再インストール

また、画像読み込みに際して下記の事項を確認済みです。
**・ソースはgitで管理されており、以前は画像を読み込めていたブランチでもダメになった。**
・ファイル名が正しいこと
・拡張子の種類は".png"であること
・拡張子は全て小文字で統一されていること
**・Xcode7.2で別プロジェクト新規作成しての画像読み込みは正常に動作する**

なおXcode6.4と7.2は下記のように共存させています。
Xcode6_4.app
Xcode7_2.app

以上、どなたかお知恵をお貸し頂けると助かります。

Comment: xcassetsを使わないケースでは正常に読めるのでしょうか？ また、その画像ファイルは、ここには貼れないような物ですか？

Comment: iOS9 SimRuntime を入れると、Xcode6 の ImageAssets が正しく生成されないという問題があるみたいですね。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911627/image-resources-xcassets-not-displayed-correctly-on-yosemite-in-application-bu